# Javascript: Uncaught ReferenceError: tb is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

**app.js**

```
"use strict";
var tb = {
    rahmen: {
        eigenschaften: [
            "hochwertig",
            "verwindungssteif",
            "vergleichsweise verwindungssteif",
            "sehr verwindungssteif",
            "sehr hohe Verwindungssteifigkeit",
            "hohe Steifigkeit"
        ]
    }
};
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ((Some Head-Tags))
  <script src="dist/app.js" defer></script>
  ((Some Head-Tags))
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <script>
        console.log(tb.rahmen.eigenschaften[3]);
      </script>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error Message**
*Uncaught ReferenceError: tb is not defined*

**The problem**
It must be something simple, but after reading many posts I still have no clue.
Why is my Javascript-Object still undefined.

Sorry, for the dump question.
Thanks,
Musa

Comment: you defer loading `app.js` in the header. Try removing `defer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you have `defer` on your `script` tag for `app.js`, so that code isn't run until after all the HTML has been parsed. But your *inline* `script` trying to use `tb` isn't deferred, so it will run as soon as it's encountered, which is *during* the HTML parsing and thus before `app.js` is run.

The spec [has a great graphic](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-async) showing what `defer` and such do:

[image]

I'd suggest keeping all of the logic in `app.js` and removing the second `script`. If you need to add content there with your script, do it via the DOM after the HTML has been parsed.

For instance, if you wanted to add content there:

`app.js`:

```js
"use strict";
var tb = {
    rahmen: {
        eigenschaften: [
            "hochwertig",
            "verwindungssteif",
            "vergleichsweise verwindungssteif",
            "sehr verwindungssteif",
            "sehr hohe Verwindungssteifigkeit",
            "hohe Steifigkeit"
        ]
    }
};
document.getElementById("main-section-content").textContent = tb.rahmen.eigenschaften[3];
```

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ((Some Head-Tags))
  <script src="dist/app.js" defer></script>
  ((Some Head-Tags))
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <div id="main-section-content"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that now there's just one `script`, which does its work when loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the graphic. That helped me a lot. And also thanks for all the other answers! You are great, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Remove defer. That should help and fix the issue.